# How to generate a matrix of two number in python

Tags: python, matrix, random, theano

Suppose `X` is a matrix. The following commands generate a matrix with the shape of `X` in randomly selected the members between `0` and `1` (`80%` of the members are `1` and the rest `0`).

```
srng = RandomStreams()    
srng.binomial(X.shape, p=0.8)
```

The question is how to make the similar random matrix between `1` and another number likes `2.5`. In another word, I need a matrix with the shape of `X` in randomly selected the members between `1` and `2.5` (`80%` of the members are `1` and the rest `2.5`)

Answer (score 1):

the same way you make a line that cross 2 point in the plane

```
y = m*x + a
```

choose `m` and `a` such that when x=0 is the lower extreme of the interval and when x=1 is the other extreme.

So for the interval `[a,b]` it is `y = (b-a)x + a`

In this case for [1,2.5] then a=1 and m=1.5, but in your case `a` is a matrix of pure 1.

Maybe your library have some other utility to do it, but when everything else fail this always will work

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import random

def create_matrix(width, height):
    mat = []
    for i in range(height):
        mat.append([]) # create sublist for each height level
        for _ in range(width):
            # generate a random number in inclusive range [1, 5]
            random_number = random.randint(1, 5)
            # 80% chance the number is one of 1, 2, 3, or 4 (arbitrary; could be 1, 3, 4, or 5, just not the entire range)
            if random_number in {1, 2, 3, 4}:
                mat[i].append(1)
            # 20% chance it's 5
            else:
                mat[i].append(2.5)
    return mat
```

One result:

```
>>> print(create_matrix(10, 10))
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5], [2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5], [1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1], [1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1]]
```

We can verify the number of `1`s and `2.5`s matches (or gets very close to) the proportion you designated:

```
>>> {number: [val for row in mat for val in row].count(number) for number in {1, 2.5}}
{1: 82, 2.5: 18}
```

With many iterations, these proportions will approach 80% and 20%, respectively. But random chance creates some variation around those means.

Note that this doesn't ensure at all that each row has at least one `2.5` (don't know if that's relevant to your problem). But this should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking to directly generate a matrix with 2.5 values, you can manually replace 0 values :

```
srng = RandomStreams()    
A = srng.binomial(X.shape, p=0.8)
A[A == 0]=2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((3, 4))
a = np.random.binomial(1, p=0.8, size=x.shape).astype(float)
a[a==0] = 2.5
```

Now `a` looks like this:

```
array([[ 1. ,  1. ,  2.5,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  2.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  2.5,  1. ]])
```

The line:

```
a[a==0] = 2.5
```

replaces all occurrences of of `0` with `2.5`.